# Htaccess ignoring directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, plesk

A couple of hours ago I've bought a VPS with Plesk and was transferring one of my websites from my webhost to my VPS. The website is made with Bootstrap and most of the pages are .php files. On my webhost I used a .htaccess file in order to direct pages without using the .php extension.

Currently, I'm using a .htaccess but it seems like it is ignoring the directory. For example: if I direct to http://mywebsite.com/php-page it works, but if I direct to http://mywebsite.com/folder/php-page it doesn't work and I get a white page with "File not found." written on it.

Rewrite is enabled in Plesk.

I'm using Plesk v12.5.30 with PHP-FPM on CentOS Linux 7.2.15.11.

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I've Googled and searched here on Stack, but nothing works. Hopefully, some of you can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding root-slash:

from:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I'm still getting the "File not found." text.

Comment: It is recognizing the folder, but the URL's are getting messed up. If I go to mywebsite.com/folder/php-page and click on a link to another page it just adds a folder/php-page to the already existing URL, instead of refreshing the whole url.

For example: mywebsite.com/folder/php-page -> mywebsite.com/folder/php-page/folder/php-page or mywebsite.com/folder/php-page/php-page/php-page

Comment: I solved it. Apparently I needed to add a "/" at the base of the url. For example: instead of <a href="php-file" it needed to be <a href="/php-file"

Thanks!